# Google Drive API consent to create and read file not edit

Tags: google-drive-api, file-permissions

Scope supports drive.readonly or drive full access.

Is it possible for the API to have only create and read consent on a file, but not update?

Again, API consent permission, not user permissions.

Comment: No, but surely this is where your app comes in to implement fine grained permissions. It might be worth sharing a bit of info on your use case.

Comment: Our app needs to have only create a doc permission and the permission to share it with other users. We don't want our app to have edit permissions on the doc to avoid any issues "your app replaced my document"